# Local variable result defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming, and I have a problem to set a variable correctly. Thanks to help me to understand the error.

the boolean variable "result" give me this error :
**Local variable result defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final**

```
boolean result = false;

do {
   Id = utils.generateId(SecurityConstants.NUM);
   listId.forEach((object) -> { if (object.getValueId().equals(Id)){result = true;}});
} while (result == true);
```

I've read many post but i could found some answer close to my error

Comment: Look at the right of this page, in the "Related" section. There are 6 other questions asking about the same error message.

Comment: Use a standard for loop instead of the `forEach` method and it will work.

Comment: use `result = listId.stream().anyMatch(object -> object.getValueId().equals(Id));` instead. It will resolve both the problem and the incorrect usage of `forEach`...

Comment: @JB Nizet Thanks to try to help but to say this post is duplicated doesn't help me to understand. As I said I've read many post and I don't understand and as i said i'm new in programming. :) thanks to have understanding mind

Comment: Well, as the first sentence of the anser to the duplicate says, "You cannot change the local variable from the body of lambda expression.". Is there somthing you don't understand in this sentence? If so, what?

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko now it gives me the same error with **Id**.  id is define out side of the loop too as ```String Id;```

Comment: @JBD declaring `final finalId = Id;` between these 2 lines and using that `finalId` might be a hot workaround. Anyway, read the linked question to understand the real cause.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It works well like this. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @JBD Sure, it will work :) But don't stick to it, please

Comment: @JBNizet Well i don't understand why it's like this. It works well if you don't use it in a loop. Knowing that it's not working, it good, but knowing why it's not working it's better, it helps to progress ...   So if you can explain to me why it's not working will be beautiful...  :)

Comment: @adnan_e With a normal loop ```for (int index = 0; index < listId.size(); index++ )``` it resolves also the issue. **@everyone** so what is the best practice to make a "clean" coding ? the method of Andrew Tobilko or of adnan_e ?